# Need to append a line after a word in a file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I have a file and content is below.

```
subscription-manager register --org="Default_Organization" --activationkey="Dev Activation Key" &> /var/log/subs2.log
```

I want to append a few words

```
(--serverurl=https://siedgeprodsatellitelb.siedgemanagement.com:8443/rhsm
--baseurl=https://siedgeprodsatellitelb.siedgemanagement.com/pulp/repos) after --activationkey="Dev Activation Key"
```

So that it can look like below

```
sudo subscription-manager register --org="LDEdgeDevices" --activationkey="Dev Activation Key" --serverurl=https://siedgeprodsatellitelb.siedgemanagement.com:8443/rhsm --baseurl=https://siedgeprodsatellitelb.siedgemanagement.com/pulp/repos &> /var/log/subs2.log
```

I am using this sed command but it is throwing an error:

```
sed -i '/"Dev Activation Key"/ s/$/--serverurl=https://siedgeprodsatellitelb.siedgemanagement.com:8443/rhsm --baseurl=https://siedgeprodsatellitelb.siedgemanagement.com/pulp/repos /' test
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: _I have a file_ : How is this file being used? If this is i.e. a shell script, you certainly don't want to modify it by _sed_.

Comment: After [asking 6 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17426313/pravin-kumar) you should know by now how to format your input/output/code as Code Blocks. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Also just saying `it is throwing error` is like taking your car to the mechanic and just saying `it is not working` and expecting them to fix it - tell us what the error message is and anything else that could help us to help you debug your script.

Answer (score 1):

> sed -i '/"Dev Activation Key"/
> s/$/--serverurl=https://siedgeprodsatellitelb.siedgemanagement.com:8443/rhsm
> --baseurl=https://siedgeprodsatellitelb.siedgemanagement.com/pulp/repos /' test

Problem with that command: you have both `/` which should be treated by `sed` as command delimiters and `/` which should be treated as literal `/` (part of string), either escape `/` which should be treated as literal `/` or use another command delimiter (use character which does not appear inside string), consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/123/abc
https://www.example.com/abc/123
```

and lets' say you want to replace `/123/` using `/456/` then you can do

```
sed 's/\/123\//\/456\//' file.txt
```

or

```
sed 's|/123/|/456/|' file.txt
```

to get output

```
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/456/abc
https://www.example.com/abc/123
```

*(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)*

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo sed -i 's%subscription-manager register --org="Default_Organization" --activationkey="Dev Activation Key"%subscription-manager register --org="Default_Organization" --activationkey="Dev Activation Key" --serverurl=https://siedgeprodsatellitelb.siedgemanagement.com:8443/rhsm --baseurl=https://siedgeprodsatellitelb.siedgemanagement.com/pulp/repos%g' test
```

Just changed / to % as when ever in sed command we have / already added in arguments we need to use different character so used % here and all remains the same

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).